# How do i get list of all installed packages in ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, jruby

I want to get list of all installed packages on my machine using ruby gem or plugin. Functionality is similar to dpkg -l command on ubuntu. Is  there any appropriate ruby gem or plugin available to get the same?

Comment: gem list is a command which gives list of all gems for a particular gemset, here i have to access list of all installed packages on local machine through gem or plugin.

Comment: @Monk_Code: Now I notice your comment, all credit to ya.

Comment: @user2964509: Trust `gem list`. Speaking about gemsets, "gemset" is a term used by `rvm`. I don't know whether rvm perhaps has any advanced ways of telling the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Ruby gems, then

```
gem list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a shell command inside the ruby interpreter. In your case, simply run

```
`dpkg -l`
```

The output will be a string containing the output of the command. Please note the `.

Keep in mind there are [several ways to perform a shell command in Ruby](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html).

Comment: `dpkg -l` will return me unprocessed data. I want to assess it through gem or api so that i can get its processed data. for ex list of all installed pkgs in form of array of hash 

[{:Name=>"ii", :Version=>"3.8.4-1ubuntu1", :Architecture=>"amd64", :Description=>"Messaging account plugin for AIM"}, {....}]

Comment: So, you are looking for Ruby bindings to APT? Or what *is* it you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Debian package called `ruby-debian` (in older Debian releases it is called `dpkg-ruby`) which contains Ruby bindings to `dkpg`.

Note: it relies on a C extension, so it will not work on Ruby implementations that don't support them, such as IronRuby.